# Numberpicker gives an issue in list view in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom numberpicker in my listview. I add quantity in numberpicker for first item in my list but when I scroll through the list then without adding the same quantity appears in random items numberpicker. How to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer is too late when I face same problem and resolve it then I think I must share my answer.

```
if (row == null) { holder.numpicker.setMaxValue(100);
    holder.numpicker.setMinValue(0);
       holder.numpicker.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
       holder.numpicker.setFocusable(false);
}
else
{

}

 holder.numpicker.setMaxValue(100);
    holder.numpicker.setMinValue(0);
    holder.numpicker.setValue(0);
       holder.numpicker.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
       holder.numpicker.setFocusable(false);
```